# Ordering CAML results

Tags: list, caml-query, ordering

Follow up to this question: [CAML is ordering by content type even though not specified](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101739/caml-is-ordering-by-content-type-even-though-not-specified/)

I have the following query:

```
<Where>
<And>
    <Or>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus' />
            <Value Type='ModStat'>0</Value>
        </Eq>
        <BeginsWith>
            <FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' />
            <Value Type='ContentTypeId'>0x0120</Value>
        </BeginsWith>
    </Or>
    <And>
        <Geq>
            <FieldRef Name='Number' />
            <Value Type='Lookup'>0</Value>
        </Geq>
        <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name='ID' />
            <Value Type='Counter'>0</Value>
        </Neq>
    </And>
</And>
</Where>
<OrderBy>
     <FieldRef Name='NumberOf' LookupId='True' />
</OrderBy>
<GroupBy Collapse='True'>
    <FieldRef Name='NumberOf' />
</GroupBy>
```

It works well, however not every list item has a value for the column 'NumberOf', so when my results are returned, with the numbers grouped at the bottom of the results, like this:

[image]

Is it possible to have the opposite, where the ordered 'NumberOf' column with numbers are first (ie. 2,3,5) and null values afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your OrderBy to Descending:

```
<OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name='NumberOf' LookupId='True' Ascending='False' />
</OrderBy>
```

Comment: if you put more details about it really great.

Comment: This works, but the numbers would be in descending order.

I essentially would like to have the Order By clause return the data so that the 'null' values in the 'NumberOf' column are after the 'not-null' values.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you can do is to order it by the NumberOf field descending (Ascending='False'), so you'd have 5, 3, 2, null. In either case, you'll need logic after calling this query to resort the result set to meet your needs.