# group by and count in caml

Tags: javascript, caml-query

I need to create chart using JavaScript from SharePoint 2010 list data .I am stuck to create data structure.

Status: Pending
Department: XYZ
Number-row:10

Please help me to create caml query implement group by and count.

Thanks

Comment: You want list items where status = pending and department = xyz and get 10 rows of item only ?

Comment: Check that: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43262/how-to-use-groupby-in-caml-query