# grouping the returned data using REST API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, api

can i use grouping to eliminate duplication on the returned values using REST API ?or is there any other way the remove\delete duplicated values using REST?

Comment: Refer this link - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/226218/sharepoint-rest-api-get-distinct-values-from-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Search API **trimduplicates**

```
    var searchApi='/_api/search/query?querytext=%27ContentType:"CT Name"
    var selectedParameter='&trimduplicates=true&selectproperties=%27,Title,Path%27';
    var searchQuery=_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl+searchApi+' %27'+selectedParameter;
```